# How to insert element in binary tree by recursion?

Tags: binary-tree

```
void Btree<T>::InsertNode2(T data, BtreeNode* root)
{
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        root = new BtreeNode (data);
        return ;
    }
    if (data <= root->data)
        InsertNode2(data, root->leftchild);
    else
        InsertNode2(data, root->rightchild);
}
```

Why isn't it right? The root can't be assigned correctly. After calling the function it's still NULL.

Comment: Consider if you are passing root by value or reference, depending on your language. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492184/binary-tree-root-is-null

Comment: Thanks. You 're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost correct. Just, as said by @DragonMoon, all you need to do is to pass `root` by reference

```
void Btree<T>::InsertNode2(T data, BtreeNode &* root)
{
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        root = new BtreeNode (data);
        return ;
    }
    if (data <= root->data)
        InsertNode2(data, root->leftchild);
    else
        InsertNode2(data, root->rightchild);
}
```