# initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue when calling a function

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I identify a binary tree like this:

```
class Btree
{
public:
    BtreeNode <T>* root;
    ...
}
```

Then I write an insert function in the binary tree class like this:

```
void Btree<T>::InsertNode2(T data, BtreeNode <T>* &root)
{
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        root = new BtreeNode <T> (data);
        //cout << root->data << endl;
        return ;
    }
    if (data <= root->data)
        InsertNode2(data, root->leftchild);
    else
        InsertNode2(data, root->rightchild);
}
```

When I call this function:

```
Btree<int> *tree=new Btree<int>();
tree->InsertNode2(1, tree->root);
```

It's alright. Everything is OK.

But if I write another function to get root:

```
BtreeNode <T>* GetRoot(){ return this->root; }
```

When I call InsertNode2:

```
Btree<int> *tree=new Btree<int>();
tree->InsertNode2(1, tree->GetRoot());
```

There is an error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue.
What's the difference between the two methods? How to modify it? I want root to be private.

Comment: The difference is that `tree->root` is the member variable, but `tree->GetRoot()` is a copy of that member variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `InsertNode2` function is a private detail of your tree. Your tree should have a public insertion interface as follows:

```
class Btree
{
    BtreeNode <T>* root;

public:
    void Insert(const T& data) { InsertNode2(data, root); }

    // ...
};
```

The tree root should of course also be a private detail of your tree.

Your `GetRoot` function returns a *copy* of the root pointer, and of course it makes no sense to try and modify the copy. You probably shouldn't even *have* a `GetRoot` function, because see above.

Comment: InsertNode2 function is also public. Everything in the binary tree class is public but the error still occurs.

Comment: @user7857293: careful with the details. I didn't say that `InsertNode2` "has `private` access", I said it "is a private detail". I was talking about the design, not the code details. The code details resulting from the design are that the function *should* have `private` access only, but that's a secondary concern. Understand the design first before you implement.

Comment: I have to think for a while-_-!. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Take your BtreeNode pointer by value not by reference. For example

```
void Btree<T>::InsertNode2(T data, BtreeNode <T>* root)
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work. You can see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373161/how-to-insert-element-in-binary-tree-by-recursion

Comment: Take a look at this article. It has wonderful explanation on how to build a binary tree [http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html]

Comment: The return type of `tree->GetRoot()` is an rvalue (in simple words a constant) and it cannot be passed to a function that is taking a reference.